# Error in create a correct table on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I try to create a table and is give me a no sense error., i attach the example:

```
create table PARAM(

id_code varchar(15) not null
weight double not null
measure varchar(2) not null
widht double
height double
lenght double
code varchar(15) not null
value double not null
loc varchar(3) not null
primary key(id_code)
);
```

And is give me the error: Error 1064! I mean everything is correct and I don't have any idea why i recieve this error

Comment: Please provide the complete error message. Error 1064 looks like a SQL syntax error - at least, you are missing the commas after each column definition

Comment: You have a incorrect syntax to use weight double

Comment: if you are stating "everything is correct" then why asking for corrections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't appear to have any commas after your columns

```
create table PARAM(

id_code varchar(15) not null,
weight double not null,
measure varchar(2) not null,
widht double,
height double,
lenght double,
code varchar(15) not null,
value double not null,
loc varchar(3) not null,
primary key(id_code)
);
```

Comment: that is., thanks is working now

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the comma at the end of every column/field declaration.

```
create table PARAM(
    id_code varchar(15) not null,
    weight double not null,
    measure varchar(2) not null,
    widht double,
    height double,
    lenght double,
    code varchar(15) not null,
    value double not null,
    loc varchar(3) not null,
    primary key(id_code)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are missing a comma after every column declaration

the syntax should be like

```
CREATE TABLE TableName(

`column name1` <Data Type>,
`column name2` <Data Type>,
.
.
.
`column name N` <Data Type>
);
```

check the [MySQL DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)  for more information

so the correct query is

```
CREATE TABLE PARAM(

id_code VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
weight DOUBLE NOT NULL,
measure VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
widht DOUBLE,
height DOUBLE,
lenght DOUBLE,
code VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
value DOUBLE NOT NULL,
loc VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id_code)
);
```

check here
[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba5fe)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
CREATE TABLE PARAM(
`id_code` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
`weight` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`measure` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
`widht` DOUBLE, `height` DOUBLE, 
`lenght` DOUBLE, 
`code` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
`value` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`loc` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_code`)
)
```

I think you have forgotten putting commas between columns.